# Is there any plan in place to remedy the dearth of Moderators on this site?

Tags: discussion, moderation

I feel empathy for the moderators who are left after the fiasco perpetrated by upper management that led to the dismissal of some of the best moderators and the resignation in protest of others.  This site has suffered greatly as a result.

Are any solutions in the works to assist the overwhelmed Mods?

Comment: Elections will be coming, hopefully very soon.

Comment: It is called **patience**! Some sites are actually moderatorless.

Comment: how does one participate in selecting moderators?

Comment: [There's an election going on. What's happening and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/135360), and [events timeline](https://stackexchange-timeline.webflow.io)

Comment: @SamuelLiew I see no evidence of an election

Comment: @KorvinStarmast that was in reply to "how does one participate in selecting moderators?"

Comment: @SamuelLiew Oh, OK, I see what was going on there, ,sorry.  We have had elections here before, so I am not sure what was behind Kris' question.

Comment: No elections before March it seems, [according to this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/343434/writing-desperately-needs-moderators).

Answer (score 5):

**Is there any plan in place to remedy the dearth of Moderators on this site?**

It will come, but the dearth of moderators on this site is not the worst in the system. Some site do not have any moderators at all.

The best we can do now is be patient and pray. After all we are Christians and Christians know how to pray, especially for our remaining moderators.

With so many moderators resigning throughout the system, I catch myself asking if the delay is not in part in waiting to see if more are going to resign fairly soon and thus the community moderators could know what number of moderators to place for particular elections. But that takes time!

In the mean time let us help Peter and Mason in performing their office by editing, flagging and voting for the good of Christianity SE.

Also allow me to thank both Peter and Mason for their hard work.

Answer (score 4):

I asked for a mod election last week, I should have asked right after Nathaniel and Caleb resigned, I don't know why they'd need me to ask since they've got all the data.

If you want to email community@stackexchange.com to ask for an election, that might get a fire going.  I have no idea what they're waiting for.  Must be a lot of red tape there.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: no, nothing being done for our one overworked mod

> Are any solutions in the works to assist the overwhelmed Mods?

Your answer beyond "no" is in the upper room(CSE chat); scroll up and down from [this post by our last surviving mod](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/53312672#53312672).

I found out from curiousdani that appointing a pro tem mod is apparently not going to happen.

The not as short answer is: with three community managers gone, the assets up the chain above diamond mods, that mods used to be able to interact with to get an election started, have been reduced.  There is a process that takes time and resources.  We have to wait until the time and resources are made available.

Until then, please support your local mod.  :)

Comment: Thanks any suggestions yiu can add on how best to assist peter without unintentionally adding to his load?

Comment: @Kris be active in the review queues and coach / mentor any new users

Comment: @Kris I'd say keep flagging problematic posts and comments. If Peter sees multiple flags on the one post then he won't have to think as hard about whether it's objectionable or not.

Comment: @Kris it's currently not terribly hard to handle the flags on this site _most_ things are pretty cut and dry and I haven't seen the flag queue over 6 or 7;  average flag handling time is still 6-7 hours, I think we were at around 2-3 hours when we had a full slate of mods.

Comment: @PeterTurner What are the odds that Mason is able to offer us more?  I saw a few of his MSE posts in the past months, and get the impression that he's feeling the kinds of frustrations Caleb and Monica and some others have felt.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast he's around, if he wasn't I'd be toast.   I think he's more active on StackOverflow and other sites, from what I remember he was a pretty active on the Delphi tag there, him and Jim McKeeth (who used to hang out here as well) were pretty helpful to me in my formative days.

Answer (score 1):

I think SO is taking a slow burn on trying to re-ramp diamonds. Exhibit A would be Space.SE, which is [on the verge of a pro-tempore election](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1426/announcing-a-pro-tempore-moderator-election)

Apparently they have no idea if [people would want the job](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1411/january-2020-moderator-election-community-interest-check) (it's bad when you have to explicitly ask). If they find success around the network, I would expect elections on all sites that lost moderators. DIY.SE had one immediately when a moderator resigned in 2018 (before the current debacle).